# MonoTouch check amount data consumption

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I've made an MonoTouch app for the iPhone where the data is accessed by several web services. Because the clients have a subscription to a phonecompany, they have a max. amount of data to consume per month.

Now my question, how can I check the amount of data that is consumed during the run of the app on the iPhone?

grtz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

You can hook up an iOS device to it by setting the proxy to a machine running Fiddler.

Among just being able to see the size of each request, you can inspect the traffic.  Great tool to have.

Comment: This might maybe work, but I have a MacBook and I the system requirements say Windows XP / 2K3 / Vista / 2K8 / Win7 / Win8